# Multiple background colors and images in full-width div

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to make a header for a site that has multiple background colors and images. On the left is a tan-ish gradient and a logo image, on the right is a sunburst/cloud image that fades to teal, as shown below.

[image: header]

The left (logo) portion should be 230px wide, and the right (sunburst) portion should be 770px wide, for a total of 1000px, and this should be centered. The left side tan gradient should extend to the left edge of the browser, and the teal should extend to the right edge.

I attempted to do it with percentages:

CSS:

```
#header {
  height: 105px;
  min-width: 1000px;
}
#header .left {
  width: 31%;
  background: url(../images/header_left_gradient.png) bottom left repeat-x;
  height: 105px;
  float: left;
}
#header .left #logo {
  float: right;
  width: 230px;
}
#header .right {
  width: 69%;
  background: url(../images/header-right.png) bottom left no-repeat #009eb0;
  height: 105px;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="header">
    <div class="left">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="./media/images/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
```

This almost worked, but the header didn't stay centered with wide browsers.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fufJ2/)

Comment: so your question has nothing to do w the background and all that.. its just a matter of centering the header?

Comment: Centering the header with both background colors/images extending to the full width of the browser.

Comment: oh that wasn't clear from the question.. can you jsfiddle it?

Comment: Added a fiddle link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this in a bit of a hacky way. First, I added a container around the header like @Raad suggested, then added two more divs inside to hold my colors:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="filler-left">
  </div>
  <div id="filler-right">
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="left">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="./media/images/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
#header-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header-wrap #filler-left {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 105px;
  background: url(../images/header_left_gradient.png) bottom left repeat-x;
}
#header-wrap #filler-right {
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 105px;
  background: #009eb0;
}
#header {
  height: 105px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

and set my .left and .right divs to fixed width. Worked out pretty well. Not my ideal solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

set header margin & width:

```
#header {
    height: 105px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}


#header .left {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF00FF;
    float: right;
    height: 105px;
    width: 31%;
}


#header .right {
    background: url("../images/header-right.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #009EB0;
    float: left;
    height: 105px;
    width: 69%;
}
```

this is worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't do anything because min-width is set, rather than width.

Comment: you need to set width,this is really important.

Comment: If I set a static width the colors don't extent to the edge of the browser, which is the main point of this question.

Comment: This results in basically the same thing I came up with. Because of the percentages it doesn't stay centered in wide browsers. It sort of goes off to the left.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but this should do the trick:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 105px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

you could use a wrapper div to apply the text-align to instead of the body, but I posted this in case you don't want to change the structure.

Comment: I tried to get this to work a few different ways, but nothing worked out. The best I could get this to do was center the #header with the colors not extending out.